# Zero-rebate barrier option pricing under the Heston model

Tags: heston, call, barrier, fourier-transform

I'm trying to derive an approximation for the zero-rebate barrier option under the Heston model:
$$dS_t=\mu S_tdt+\sqrt{v_t}S_tdW^S_t$$
$$dv_t=\kappa(\bar{v}-v_t)dt+\eta\sqrt{v_t}dW^v_t,\quad d\langle W^S,W^v\rangle_t=\rho dt$$
The payoff of a down-and-out option is:
$$\mathcal{C}_T=(S_T-k)\mathbb{I}_{\{S_T\geq K\}}\mathbb{I}_{\{(\max_{0\leq t\leq T}S_t=:)m_T\geq H\}}$$

Under the Black-Scholes dynamics we have the closed-form solution:
$$\mathcal{C}_t=S_te^{r\tau}\left(\Phi\left(\frac{\ln(S_t/K)+\nu\tau}{\sigma\sqrt{\tau}}\right)-\left(\frac{H}{S_t}\right)^{1+2r/\sigma^2}\Phi\left(\frac{\ln(H^2/(S_tK))+\nu\tau}{\sigma\sqrt{\tau}}\right)\right) 
- K\left(\Phi\left(\frac{\ln(S_t/K)+(\nu-\sigma^2)\tau}{\sigma\sqrt{\tau}}\right)-\left(\frac{H}{S_t}\right)^{-1+2r/\sigma^2}\Phi\left(\frac{\ln(H^2/(S_tK))+(\nu-\sigma^2)\tau}{\sigma\sqrt{\tau}}\right)\right)$$
where $\nu=r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$
Obviously, under the Heston dynamics we don't have a closed-form solution. However, I would like to know whether there exists approximations allowing to price the down-and-out call option in a similar fashion.

As a starting point, I can use the result of the hitting probability of Heston for $\rho$ and $\mu$ equal to 0, i.e. the probability that during the time interval $[0,t]$ the process $S_t$ was positive, with $x$ and $y$ are initial values, solved via the Fourier transform in $x$: 
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sin (\omega x)}{\omega}\bigg(\frac{\Delta(\omega)e^{-m_-(\omega)\kappa t}}{m_+(\omega)+m_-(\omega)e^{-\Delta(\omega)\kappa t}}\bigg)^{\frac{2\theta\kappa}{\xi^2}}e^{-\frac{2y\kappa}{\xi^2}B(\omega,\kappa t)}d\omega$$
where $B(\omega,\tau)$ is a solution of the Riccati equation 
$$\frac{\partial B}{\partial \tau}(\omega,\tau)=-B(\omega,\tau)-B(\omega,\tau)^2+\frac{\xi^2 \omega^2}{4\kappa^2}, B(\omega,0)=0;$$
$$\Delta(\omega)=\sqrt{1+(\xi\omega/\kappa)^2}, m_{\pm}(\omega)=\frac{\Delta(\omega)\pm 1}{2}$$

Any hints in this direction as much as completely different solutions are much appreciated.

Comment: If I can ask, is this just a mathematical challenge, or is there a real world motivation behind it? Pricing this with finite differences is straightforward and trivial to implement if you already have a vanilla Heston FD engine.

Comment: @YianPap good point! It's mainly a math challenge actually, although I'm seeking an alternative to Monte Carlo pricing with importance sampling which works well for discretely monitored barriers but cannot reproduce the price for continuously monitored barriers. I don't have a vanilla Heston FD engine, but I guess it is also a valid approach worth being considered. Although it only works in low dimensions right?

Comment: Right, if you want high dimensions then you only have MC. You can make your MC price continuously monitored barriers pretty accurately though. In the link below I talk about this a little and show some results for Heston: https://www.acenumerics.com/miscellaneous/monte-carlo-pricing-of-continuously-monitored-barrier-options-with-heston

Comment: @YianPap so basically you mean to use the Brownian Bridge result for a GBM like the one I wrote above? Also, for comparison, would you please write an answer about the exact PDE-based solution with full-truncation Euler discretisation?

Comment: PDE approach uses finite differences to solve the backward kolmogorov equation associated with the process $(S_t, v_t)$. There's no need for "full truncation Euler discretization" which is a technique used to ensure that $v_t$ does not become negative in a MC simulation. Because Heston is a 2 dim model to implement FD you need a FD engine for the backward kolmogorov PDE associated with a 2 dim diffusion process. These are usually implemented using ADI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_direction_implicit_method#Example:_2D_diffusion_equation.

Comment: Right, so what I was saying was that it is easier to keep using MC and add the probabilistic correction to get good accuracy for continuously monitored barrier options. The reason I didn't use the truncated Euler scheme for my MC experiment was that this would add an extra (time-discretization) error and would cloud the conclusion about how well the probabilistic correction is in removing the "simulation bias". But if you were happy with it for vanilla options, then you can still use it for barriers.

Comment: @YianPap thanks! Would you mind writing this probabilistic correction in mathematical terms, please? I sort of understood your idea, but the implementation is still not that clear to me.

Comment: This paper explains it in section 1: "Advanced Monte Carlo methods for barrier and related exotic options", by Emmanuel Gobet (https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00319947/document) I suggest you read that first and then my comments in the blog about applying this technique to Heston.